# Term for making a php/html table using data from sql table, but php table values are calculated from sql data

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I've got the following working for printing the data from the sql table. 
However, I have two goals.

1. There is a creditcardTotal field that I'd also like to use to make a dailyTotal value. That is what I really want to print. However, I do not want to have a dailyTotal value on the sql side as the data goes back for a while and I don't want to manually update the database.
2. Once I get the dailyTotal working, I'd like to add those up for a monthlyTotal value.

Honestly, if I could figure out how to actually get the data out of `.$data['CashTotal']`. I could probably figure out how to calculate everything myself.

The ultimate goal is to have a a PHP table that shows the dates and the daily totals for a month (for each day) then a total at the bottom.

I can't figure out the term to search to show me what I'm wanting to do.

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from HP_Closing_Count WHERE '2017-01-01' <=     Date and Date < '2017-02-01'");

echo '<table border=2px>';  // opening table tag
echo'<th>Date</th>
<th>Employee</th>
<th>CashTotal</th>
'; //table headers



while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

// we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table
echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
echo '<td>'.$data['Date'].'</td>
<td>'.$data['Employee'].'</td>
<td>'.$data['CashTotal'].'</td>
'; // we are looping all data to be printed till last row in the table
echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
}

echo '</table>';  //closing table tag

?>
```

Date    Employee    CashTotal

2017-01-04  Jon 931.25

2017-01-05  Robin   0

2017-01-07  Jon 383.5

2017-01-06  Jay 275.25

2017-01-08  Jon 417.5

2017-01-09  Jay 297.75

2017-01-10  Colwyn C    280.5

2017-01-11  Colwyn  344

2017-01-12  Ellen   374.5

2017-01-13  Jay 288.5

2017-01-14  Jay 377.75

2017-01-15  Jay 349.25

2017-01-16  Jay 376.5

2017-01-17  Colwyn  248.5

2017-01-18  Taylor  210.5

2017-01-19  COLWYN  247

2017-01-20  Jay 330.75

2017-01-21  Jay 475.75

2017-01-22  Jay 489.75

2017-01-23  Jay 344

2017-01-24  Parker  321.25

2017-01-25  Taylor  257.25

2017-01-26  Ellen   249

2017-01-27  Jay 318.25

2017-01-28  Jay 477

2017-01-29  Jay 382

2017-01-30  Jay 271.5

2017-01-31  Ellen   230.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loop you are using to generate the table you can tally a running sum of $data['CashTotal'].  Then use that for your grand total display.

```
$grandTotal = 0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

// we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table
echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
echo '<td>'.$data['Date'].'</td>
<td>'.$data['Employee'].'</td>
<td>'.$data['CashTotal'].'</td>
'; // we are looping all data to be printed till last row in the table
echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
$grandTotal += $data['CashTotal'];
}
echo '</table>';  //closing table tag
echo 'Total: ' . $grandTotal;
```

Comment: I was typing my answer while you posted yours. Thanks. That's essentially what I did. I figured out how to get the data out too so I can add another column, CreditCards, and get a dailyTotal as well.

Comment: @assemblyhelpneededplease Props on figuring it out.  While you are learning, you should look for tutorials using [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) for database access.  The mysql functions have been deprecated for awhile, and are gone in PHP7.  No sense learning old tech.

Answer (score 0):

```
$TOTAL=0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from HP_Closing_Count WHERE '2017-01-01' <= Date and Date < '2017-02-01'");
echo '<table border=2px>';  // opening table tag
echo'<th>Date</th>
<th>Employee</th>
<th>CashTotal</th>
'; //table headers



while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$TOTAL=$TOTAL+$data['CashTotal'];
// we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table
echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
echo '<td>'.$data['Date'].'</td>
<td>'.$data['Employee'].'</td>
<td>'.$data['CashTotal'].'</td>
'; // we are looping all data to be printed till last row in the table
echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
}

echo '</table>';  //closing table tag
echo $TOTAL;
?>
```

Date    Employee    CashTotal

2017-01-04  Jon 931.25

2017-01-05  Robin   0

2017-01-07  Jon 383.5

2017-01-06  Jay 275.25

2017-01-08  Jon 417.5

2017-01-09  Jay 297.75

2017-01-10  Colwyn C    280.5

2017-01-11  Colwyn  344

2017-01-12  Ellen   374.5

2017-01-13  Jay 288.5

2017-01-14  Jay 377.75

2017-01-15  Jay 349.25

2017-01-16  Jay 376.5

2017-01-17  Colwyn  248.5

2017-01-18  Taylor  210.5

2017-01-19  COLWYN  247

2017-01-20  Jay 330.75

2017-01-21  Jay 475.75

2017-01-22  Jay 489.75

2017-01-23  Jay 344

2017-01-24  Parker  321.25

2017-01-25  Taylor  257.25

2017-01-26  Ellen   249

2017-01-27  Jay 318.25

2017-01-28  Jay 477

2017-01-29  Jay 382

2017-01-30  Jay 271.5

2017-01-31  Ellen   230.25

9549